# Web system for adding points and related information to a map

Tags: web-mapping

I have been asked to find/make a web-based system whereby members of the public can add a point to a map and then enter some details about it.

I could make this myself but as it's such a simple system I'm sure there must be an existing solution already out there.

Comment: Do you have any existing geographic information systems and software available? Do users need to be able to edit previously entered information?

Comment: I have MapInfo but I don't think that will help much! Data doesn't need to be edited after it has been entered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to make use of the WFS-T protocol which is widely supported by opensource web map servers (e.g. [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org), [Tiny-OWS](http://www.tinyows.org/trac) etc) and an [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) client as demopnstrated by http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html

Comment: As I said, I *could* build this myself but I am asking if there is an existing solution. Is this something that is possible with, say, Google Maps?

Comment: I ended up building it myself using OpenLayers.

Comment: @Mr_Chimp - is they system you built online, or written up anywhere? Just discovered this thread after posting [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19653/how-could-i-crowdsource-spatial-data-with-online-clickable-map) which is very similar.

Comment: @Simbamangu It's online here: http://www.bakerassocs.com/add_comment.php?project_id=26 If I made it again I'd probably use Leaflet instead of OpenLayers but this works. There's some PHP back-end stuff but I can't really share that.

Answer (score 5):

There are likely several out-of-the-box solutions that could suit your needs, and Google does have one. If you go to http://maps.google.com/ you can click "My Places", "Create New Map", and then "Edit". When you click "Edit", you get a few digitization tools. You can make the map private and "invite collaborators". It's pretty convenient and I have used this in the past for planning travel routes with multiple collaborators.

Comment: This looks useful but doesn't quite suit my needs as I would need to invite each person to use it and my project needs to be open to the public. Thanks all the same!

Comment: The map can be viewable by the public and editable by the people for which you grant permissions, or you can allow anyone to edit the map.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you could do that. Unfortunately anyone can also edit the title and description of the map and edit points that other people have created. I need something half way between!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [ArcGIS.com map viewer](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?useExisting=1) or [ArcGIS Explorer Online](http://explorer.arcgis.com/)?  Create a personalized map, create a group, and share it (ArcGIS.com).

[Tutorial Videos](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisonline/help/index.html#/Videos/010q00000003000000/)