# Crowdsourcing spatial data with online clickable map?

Tags: web-mapping, crowdsourcing

Here in northern Tanzania we are experiencing a huge [westward butterfly migration](http://safari-ecology.blogspot.com/) - originally those of us who saw it thought it was local but it turns out that it's very widespread. We're getting informal reports from all over, but would like to (quickly!) set up a way for people to report sightings:

- A clickable map on a web page that lets people show the location of a sighting;
- A form that collects some other basic data;
- Logging of spatial points and the form data.

Ideally this could be done through a Facebook page as social media will spread this like ... well, like a butterfly migration in a high wind ;).

Any ideas?

---

Here's the [Google Map showing sightings](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=210062539926247996439.0004b7f5ec2ede4fb7225&msa=0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

definitely it is an use case for the excellent [Crowdmap](http://crowdmap.com/) web application (based on [Ushahidi](http://www.ushahidi.com/)) here.

Comment: We're [trialling](https://tzbutterflies.crowdmap.com/) that right now! Ushahidi web app looks great (we're using the free online hosting at Crowdmap.com). Writing up the results on the [Tanzanian GIS User's Group site](http://www.tzgisug.org/wp/?p=134) as it develops.

Comment: we trialled the Crowdmap site and it worked pretty well, but the original researcher went with a shared Google map at the time. However, we're now using the same site to start [tracking invasive plants in Tanzania](https://partheniumafrica.crowdmap.com/). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try out http://opendata.socrata.com/. You can create a dataset that includes columns for some data and location columns. There is a Visualize tool that lets you visualize this data on a map, and there's also an Embed tool that lets you create a form that the public can use to submit new data.

Here's an example: http://opendata.socrata.com/Business/Seattle-Startup-Map/nhx8-7ic6. If you click on **More Views**, you can see how the owner of that dataset has created a form that can be embedded or shared elsewhere to allow new data to be submitted.

Full disclosure: I used to work at this company, but no longer do.

Comment: Have played around with that site - it looks pretty worthwhile, but takes some time to set up. From what I can tell, though, you can't actually click on the map to indicate a position, only put lat/lon or addresses in?

Comment: @Simbamangu Yeah, I think that's the case, you have to type in an address or lat/long. Not 100% sure since I haven't been there for a bit and I never worked on that feature.